# PayPal IPN stops working after time

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a strange problem on my hands. I have the below PayPal IPN script handling user activations etc. The script works FINE when using the IPN simulator (I have not yet tested it with a SandBox account). The script also works fine live. The problem is that it stops working after a couple of IPN calls. Is there any reason why this would happen? Is PayPal perhaps blocking IPN calls? I don't see why the script should work on and off. Perhaps there's something obvious I'm missing here. By all accounts the IPNs are being received on PayPal's end. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
$req .= "&$key=$value";
 } 

$headers = "From: DD Notifications\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: notifications@deep-democracy.net\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$url = "http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

if (strcmp ($result, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$item_name = $_POST['item_name1'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number1'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom_var = $_POST['custom'];

require_once("../includes/db_connection.php");


    $result_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM delegate_payments WHERE payment_id='$custom_var' AND payment_completed='No'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result_sql) == 1) {

        mysql_query("UPDATE delegate_payments SET payment_completed='Yes' WHERE payment_id='$custom_var'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_sql);
        $amount = $row['payment_amount'];
        $names_array = explode(', ', $row['payment_content']);

        $result2_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$payer_email'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2_sql);
        $current_amount = $row['amount_due'];
        $new_amount = $current_amount - $amount;

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET amount_due='$new_amount' WHERE email='$payer_email'");

        foreach ($names_array as &$value) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET activated='1' WHERE email='$value'");
            mail($value, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
            $result_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$value");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_sql);
            $name = $row['name']." ".$row['surname'];
            $city = $row['city'];
            $payee_email = $row['email'];
            $level = $row['level'];
            $country = $row['country'];
            $course_date = $row['course_date'];

        }
}

} else if (strcmp ($result, "INVALID") == 0) {

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the data being sent to your script is causing an error to be occasionally thrown. Your script is probably not handling bad or missing data correctly. What I have done in the past is put a log statement between ever line of my IPN script so that I know when the script bombs out. You should also use the Paypal Sandbox to test different scenarios.